# Avoid infinite loop with useEffect dependencies

Tags: reactjs

I am stuck in an infinite loop while trying to enforce the exhaustive dependency rule.

Take this for example - adjust the address bar when we change to a different step in a form.

```
// routes is an array like
// ['step1', 'step2']

// When we change the step (click a button) let's update the address bar
useEffect(() => {
  const route = routes[step];
  if(route){
    const path = `/${route}`;
    if(path !== location.pathname){
       history.push(path)
    }
  }
}, [history, location.pathname, routes, step]);

// When we change the address bar (press back, refresh) let's update the step
useEffect(() => {
  if(params.step){
     const step = routes.indexOf(params.step);
     if(step > -1){
        setStep(step);
     }   
  }
}, [params, routes]);
```

So what happens here - we load the page fine. We navigate with buttons fine. But then we hit back.

1. `params` changes - so we call `setStep` in the second `useEffect`. Address bar is up to date
2. But before `step` change triggers the first `useEffect`, `location.pathname` triggers it. It then uses the stale state of `step` which was the previous step, calling `history.push` and setting it back to the last step.

Continue to infinity.

Comment: Arguments that are passed into the dependencies array are compared using strict equality checks, so any value that would be recreated per render cycle will trigger that effect. One such value might be your routes array, if that array is re-created in your component. Strings, numbers and memoized objects such as the history object should be OK

Comment: The issue is that `location.pathname` changes and calls `useEffect` before `step` changes. So an old `step` value is used causing it to go back to the previous step and set the address bar to the wrong value. Then the step update comes in and moves it forward, and then it loops forever.

Comment: use `const { push } = useHistory();` and add `push` in your first `useEffect` hook. And change `params` dependency by  params.step in 2nd `useEffect`

Comment: Like I've said, the issue is `location.pathname`. Nothing you mentioned is any different than the current code.